# How to cycle between language specific abbrev tables in a buffer?

Tags: abbrev, flyspell

I have (human-)language-specific abbrev-tables named like `lang-francais-mode-abbrev-table`, `lang-castellano8-mode-abbrev-table` backed by my `~/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs` file. The language names are the ispell dictionary names.

I can't just load all the abbreviations into memory in `global-abbrev`, because I then have "collisions", e.g. "dont" stays "dont" in French, but should become "don't" for English. And "ten" and "men" should stay as is in English, but become "m'en" and "t'en" for French.

To cycle between flyspell languages, I use this function from the [emacs flyspell wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell):

```
(let ((langs '("american" "francais" "deutsch8" "castellano8")))
  (setq lang-ring (make-ring (length langs)))
  (dolist (elem langs) (ring-insert lang-ring elem)))

(defun cycle-ispell-languages ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((lang (ring-ref lang-ring -1)))
    (ring-insert lang-ring lang)
    (ispell-change-dictionary lang)))
```

I would like to change `cycle-ispell-languages` to also cycle the active language table for this buffer. How would I do that?

I know, I can `setq local-abbrev-table lang-francais-mode-abbrev-table`, but that then removes(?) the other active abbrev-tables, that other (major) modes might add, or does it?

Note: I edited out a significant portion describing me at an earlier point of the same problem.